# How to use Spring Data JPA findAll method in Spring Boot with custom parameter?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Entity class

```
@Entity
public class SampleEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 2000)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 2000)
    private String type;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 2000)
    private String something;

    // getters and setters 

}
```

What I need is to findAll by the custom column of my entity ***type***

how I can achieve this in Spring boot and JpaRepository

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-jpa-and-spring-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RC1/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html which will list all possible method to find out records from DB.

For your problem , use `List<SampleEntity> findByType(String type)` in your repository. This method will return all *SampleEntity* by *type* values passed in query.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `findByType(String type)` you can use the Spring Data repository syntax to fine tune your queries, using the same parameter `String type`.

Some examples:

- `findByTypeIgnoreCase`: will return all that match the given type string ignoring case differences between that string and the `SampleEntity` type field.
- `findFirstByType`: will return the first element with the given type if there is any.
- `findFirst100ByType`: will return the first 100 elements.
- `findByTypeOrderByIdAsc`: will return all `SampleEntity` with the given type, in ascending order by their `id` field.
- `countByType`: will return the number of `SampleEntity` with the given type.
- `removeByType`: will delete all the `SampleEntity` with that type.